# retrieving a variable value from lower level

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, this, undefined, root

well i created some variables in the main stage level, with something like this:

```
for(i=0,i<10,i++){
    var var_name="var_num_"+i;
    this[var_name]="some value";
}//<-----------------------------------------------------works
```

so i get 10 variables named "var_num0", "var_num1", "var_num2" each one with some value.
and i can acces them any where calling this

```
var second_var=MovieClip(root).var_num0;//<--------------works
```

my problem comes when i want to call all the variables from a lower level or in another frame or somewhere else using another loop:

```
var third_var;
for(j=0,j<3,j++){
third_var=this["MovieClip(root).var_num_"+j];//<---------DOSNT WORK
trace(this["MovieClip(root).var_num_"+j]);//<------------returns "undefined"
}
```

how can i make this work? i tried a lot of things and nothing...

thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

In your case both "root" and "this" are the scope you want to access the vars from. so try this:

```
var third_var:MovieClip;
for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    third_var = MovieClip(root)[var_num_ + j];
    trace(third_var);
}
```

Also you should have semi-colons in your for loop rather than comers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to preface my answer with a suggestion you use a 'Document Class' with AS3 to make things like namespaces and inheritance much clearer. You know exactly where things are accessible when using document based, object oriented programming versus the timeline programming available through the Flash IDE (its only there because of AS1/2).  Tut: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day/page14

On to the answer: You are trying to move two levels of inheritance in one set of `[]` Another way of writing your first "Doesn't work" line is:

`this.myMovieClip["var_num"+j"];`

You could also use: `this["MovieClip"]["var_num"+j];`

Basically, you need to take the "MovieClip(root)" out of the string you are using to call your variable because you are passing through two levels of inheritance: this->MovieClip->targetVar

You need to use two periods, a period and a set square bracket or two sets square brackets to move two levels of inheritance. A period `.` and a set of square brackets `[]` both accomplish the task of moving one level deeper, so putting the `.` inside the string used to call up your variable won't work.

Explanation:

The following three examples all return the same variable:

```
myMovieClip.my_variable

myMovieClip["my_variable"]

var str:String = "my_variable";
myMovieClip[str];
```